# Adding alternate mail id from Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to add an alternate email with [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) from a.Net Core app.

The `user` class in Microsoft Graph does not provide a property for adding an additional mail id.

Comment: Do you still have the issue about this problem? If yes, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 5):

You can using Azure AD Graph to add the mail id to the `otherMails`. Here is sample to update the this property:

```
PATCH: https://graph.windows.net/{tenant}/me?api-version=1.6
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{
"otherMails":["test@test.com"]
}
```

Refer the links below for the user entity and update user REST:

[Entity and complex type reference | Graph API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference)

[Update User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#UpdateUser)

Comment: Yes I saw 'OtherMails' property in Azure AD. but I want to achieve this in Microsoft graph API. Is there any property in Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: At present, the Microsoft Graph REST doesn't support this property. If you want Microsoft Graph REST to support this feature, you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). And if you still prefer using Microsoft Graph, as a workaround, you may use the [extensions](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/extensibility_overview).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the C# code to retrieve the alternate email

```cs
Select(u => new {
    u.DisplayName,
    u.Mail,
    u.UserPrincipalName,
    u.OtherMails
})
.GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the alternate email from the "otherMails" property on a User in the [Graph API Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Note that this is only returned on a Select, so you need to include the query parameter "$select=otherMails" to see it.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USER_ID?$select=otherMails
authorization: bearer {access_token}

{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(otherMails)",
    "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v2/YOUR_AAD_TENANT/directoryObjects/USER_ID/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",
    "otherMails": [
        "altEmail@website.com"
    ]
}
```